# Can someone explain how unix exit commands work?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

I have read about unix exit commands but please can someone tell me how they work exactly.

I mean what is their purpose and how can they be used.

Also i see people talking about success = 0 or something and i dont have a clue what they mean by this.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

Comment: @pogba123: Be careful with the wording: There doesn't exist a **unix** exit command (try `which exit` to find out). However, many programming languages, **including bash**, have a command named `exit`. While in particular with the *exit* command, its semantics are similar (if not identical) accross most programming language, this is not always the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "exit"  command exits the shell script

```
echo "A"
exit 1
echo "B"
```

In the above example 'echo "B"'  is not executed because of the exit statement.
It's like a return statement in normal progemming languages. The expression after the exit is the return value. Convention is that 0 means "Success"  other values means an error.
So if the above script is called q.sh, than this script can be called from an other script:

```
sh ./q.sh
echo $?
```

The code "$?" means "exit" value of the  last shell script.
Above script prints "1"